# The browser displays this kind of error

Tags: php, mysql, apache

> Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 26
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _item in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 27
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 31
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 31
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _item in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 32
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 42
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 42
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 53
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 53
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 64
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 64
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 75
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 75
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 86
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 86
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 97
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 97
>   Notice: Undefined variable: _score in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trivia\Score.php on line 107

And These is the Code:

```
<?php
$_score == null;
$_item == null;
/*1*/
If (isset($_POST['hogwarts1']) != "2") {
    $_score == $_score;
    $_item+= 1;
}

Else {
    $_score+= 1;
    $_item+= 1;
}

/*2*/
If (isset($_POST['hogwarts2']) != "1") {
    $_score == $_score;
    $_item+= 1;
}

Else {
    $_score+= 1;
    $_item+= 1;
}

/*3*/
If (isset($_POST['hogwarts3']) != "3") {
    $_score == $_score;
    $_item+= 1;
}

Else {
    $_score+= 1;
    $_item+= 1;
}

/*4*/
If (isset($_POST['hogwarts4']) != "1") {
    $_score == $_score;
    $_item+= 1;
}

Else {
    $_score+= 1;
    $_item+= 1;
}

/*5*/
If (isset($_POST['hogwarts5']) != "2") {
    $_score == $_score;
    $_item+= 1;
}

Else {
    $_score+= 1;
    $_item+= 1;
}

/*6*/
If (isset($_POST['hogwarts6']) != "3") {
    $_score == $_score;
    $_item+= 1;
}

Else {
    $_score+= 1;
    $_item+= 1;
}

/*7*/
If (isset($_POST['hogwarts7']) != "3") {
    $_score == $_score;
    $_item+= 1;
}

Else {
    $_score+= 1;
    $_item+= 1;
}

If ($_score != 0) {
    $_scoreresult = $_score . "/" . $_item;
    echo "<span class=style9>$_scoreresult</span>";
}

Else {
    $_scoreresult = "0/" . $_item;
    echo "<center><span class=style9>$_scoreresult</span></center>";
}

?>
```

Hoping for someone to help me guys.. Thank You Very Much...

Answer (score 3):

Don't use this kind of name `$_name` for your variables. Call it `$score` and use `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: Also he should initialize it with `0` not `null`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you call them $_name, it's a global standard for global variables. But if you really want to go deeper into details, you should use DEFINE().

Answer (score 1):

On your first line you are declaring variable by using `=` in stead of `==`. 
That mean change `$_score=null` to `$_score==null` and do same for `$_item` variable.

Answer (score 0):

assignment is "=" , you had "==".

This is  mistake I've made several times before.

```
<?php
$_score = null;
$_item = null;
/*1*/
```

Answer (score 0):

- `isset` returns a boolean, not the value of the tested variable.
- `==` is a comparison operation not an assignation, use `=` instead.

Here is a more factored code:

```
$score = null;
$item = null;

$answers = array(2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3);
$answersLength = count($answers);

foreach ($i = 1; $i <= $answersLength; $i++) {
    $field = sprintf('hogwarts%d', $i);

    if (!isset($_POST[$field]) || $_POST[$field] != $answers[$i]) {
        $item++;
    } else {
        $score++;
        $item++;
    }
}

if ($score != 0) {
    $scoreresult = $score . "/" . $item;
    echo "<span class=style9>$scoreresult</span>";
} else {
    $scoreresult = "0/" . $item;
    echo "<center><span class=style9>$scoreresult</span></center>";
}
```